# Space in DocumentRoot folder name

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I installed `apache2` on ubuntu,
I changed the `DocumentRoot` value to my work folder.
my folder path is `/home/user/My\ Works/sites` so I changed my `DocumentRoot` to :

> DocumentRoot /home/user/My\ Works/sites

but when I reload the apache I get this error:

> Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:
>   DocumentRoot takes one argument, Root directory of the document tree
>   Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have more
>   information.    ...fail!

What should I do if I have space in my folder name?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply quote the path:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/My Works/sites"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but my solution was adding quotes around the site that I added in httpd-vhost.conf. The URL of the site I added has a space in it, so the path required it to be in quotes.